# How to use bn-chai in a typescript test script?

Tags: dapp-development, testing, typescript, test

I would like to use [bn-chai](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/bn-chai/) plugin for chai in a test script written in typescript.
I imported (the official documentation uses require) the dependencies and set chai according documentation:

```
import { describe } from "mocha";
import { expect, use } from 'chai';
import BN = require("bn-chai");
import bnChai = require("bn-chai");

use(bnChai(BN));
```

But when I make an assertion like that below:
`expect(claimedResult[0]).to.eq.BN(10);`

Typescript don't compile the code and show the message:
`error TS2339: Property 'BN' does not exist on type 'Equal'.`

I understood that it occurs because the BN method is added dinamically to the type `eq` by the instruction `use(bnChai(BN))`.

Did anyone have success using bn-chai library in scripts written with typescript?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like following:

```
import { expect, use } from 'chai';
import { BN } from 'bn.js';
use(require('chai-bn')(BN));
```